# getting object Parse from a loop

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud

In a Parse server function, it's getting Matches and profiles.
From a query to get matches another function is called to get Profiles by id but the result is :

```
{"_resolved":false,"_rejected":false,"_reso  resolvedCallbacks":[],"_rejectedCallbacks":[]}
```

Main Query :

```
mainQuery.find().then(function(matches) {
_.each(matches, function(match) {
        // Clear the current users profile, no need to return that over the network, and clean the Profile


        if(match.get('uid1') === user.id) {
            match.set('profile2', _processProfile(match.get('profile2')))
            match.unset('profile1')
        }
        else if (match.get('uid2') === user.id) {
             var profileMatch = _getProfile(match.get('profile1').id);
             alert(">>>"+JSON.stringify(profileMatch));

            match.set('profile1', _processProfile(match.get('profile1')))
            match.unset('profile2')
        }
```

})

the function to get **Profile info**:

```
function _getProfile(id){

var promise = new Parse.Promise();



    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var queryProfile = new Parse.Query(Profile);

        return queryProfile.equalTo("objectId",id).find()
        .then(function(result){

            if(result){
                promise.resolve(result);
                alert("!!!!"+result);
            }

                else {
            console.log("Profile ID: " + id + " was not found");
            promise.resolve(null);

            }

        },
        function(error){

            promise.reject(error)
        });
        return promise;     
}
```

Comment: getting result of profile outside of the loop matches is ok

Answer (score 1):

Just found this a little late.  You've probably moved on, but for future readers: the key to solving something like this is to use promises as returns from small, logical asynch (or sometimes asynch, as in your case) operations.

The whole _getProfile function can be restated as:

```
function _getProfile(id){
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var queryProfile = new Parse.Query(Profile);
    return queryProfile.get(id);
}
```

Since it returns a promise, though, you **cannot** call it like this:

```
var myProfileObject = _getProfile("abc123");
// use result here
```

Instead, call it like this:

```
_getProfile("abc123").then(function(myProfileObject) { // use result here });
```

Knowing that, we need to rework the loop that calls this function.  The key idea is that, since the loop *sometimes* produces promises, we'll need to let those promises resolve at the end.

```
// return a promise to change all of the passed matches' profile attributes
function updateMatchesProfiles(matches) {
    // setup mainQuery

    mainQuery.find().then(function(matches) {
        var promises = _.map(matches, function(match) {
        // Clear the current users profile, no need to return that over the network, and clean the Profile

        if(match.get('uid1') === user.id) {
            match.set('profile2', _processProfile(match.get('profile2')));  // assuming _processProfile is a synchronous function!!
            match.unset('profile1');
            return match;
        } else if (match.get('uid2') === user.id) {
            var profileId = match.get('profile1').id;
            return _getProfile(profileId).then(function(profileMatch) {
                alert(">>>"+JSON.stringify(profileMatch));
                match.set('profile1', _processProfile(match.get('profile1')))
                match.unset('profile2');
                return match;
            });
        }
    });
    // return a promise that is fulfilled when all of the loop promises have been
    return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll test it later. So we have to put each promises from the loop and profile as the promise too ?

Comment: Not required, no.  The way its written, the function takes an array of matches, does something to all of them (synchronously for some, asynchronously for others), and returns a promise to finish everything that is fulfilled with the elements of the original array, now modified.  It could just as easily return just the ones that were modified asynchronously, or even none at all.